# Array undefined when referenced in a defined object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

This is probably a simple solution but it's driving me nuts. I have a line of code where I am trying to reference my array within a property. I am new with AngularJS so this might be a really stupid question.

The array is called as such:

```
console.log($scope.pickupleague.players);
```

This returns: *undefined*

Thinking that my object $scope.pickupleague isn't working, I call:

```
console.log($scope.pickupleague);
```

This, however, returns everything I am looking for. There are 7 separate items within object. Right now I am not doing anything additional for my function. The whole thing is simply just this:

```
$scope.setSubscribedPlayers = function(leagueDetails) {
        console.log($scope.pickupleague.players);
    };
```

I call this function once the $scope.pickupleague has been set. Again, to my knowledge, nothing crazy is happening. That function looks like this:

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
        $scope.pickupleague = Pickupleagues.get({ 
            pickupleagueId: $stateParams.pickupleagueId
        });

        $scope.listPlayers = $scope.setSubscribedPlayers($scope.pickupleague);
    };
```

Any help on this would be great. I am stumped and I feel like for something like this, it should be a very simple solution.

Thanks so much.

**EDIT - Added The Contents of $scope.pickupleague**

```
__v: 17
_id: "55323371b2873f32099aa435"
address: "1234 Dufferin Street"
city: "Thornhill"
contactname: "Mike L"
cost: "30"
country: "Canada"
created: "2015-04-18T10:35:29.939Z"
description: "This is just a game for some beginners to get together and play."
email: "email@gmail.com"
name: "Friday Night Hockey"
phone: "416-123-4433"
players: Array[7]
0: Object
    _id: "5540b318ffe8b25b749da4fd"
    playerID: "553fda45d014e77bc659d16f"
1: Object
    _id: "5540b3c5ffe8b25b749da4fe"
    playerID: ""
2: Object
    _id: "5540b3eeffe8b25b749da4ff"
    playerID: ""
__proto__: Object
3: Object
    _id: "5540b434ffe8b25b749da500"
    playerID: ""
__proto__: Object
4: Object
    _id: "5540b4efffe8b25b749da501"
    playerID: "553fda45d014e77bc659d16f"
__proto__: Object
5: Object
    _id: "5540b567ffe8b25b749da502"
    playerID: "553fda45d014e77bc659d16f"
__proto__: Object
6: Object
    _id: "5540b5adffe8b25b749da503"
    playerID: "552af744291bddc5b98934c0"
length: 7
__proto__: Array[0]
postalcode: "1a2 b3c"
province: "Ontario"
skillLevel: "Rookie"
time: "11:00pm - 12:00 am"
```

Comment: I guess you need to call an element of the array, not the array itself?

Comment: Your `.findOne()` function sets up a property named "listPlayers", but your original statement is looking for a property named "players".

Comment: Please post an example of the content of the object $scope.pickupleague

Comment: What is  $scope.pickupleague? a promise?

Answer (score 0):

`Pickupleagues.get({});` seems to be an asynchronous function. Therefore `$scope.pickupleague` is a promise when you call it. Put your other function in the callback of the async function:

```
$scope.findOne = function() {
    $scope.pickupleague = Pickupleagues.get({ 
        pickupleagueId: $stateParams.pickupleagueId
    }).then(function(){
        // Success callback
        $scope.listPlayers = $scope.setSubscribedPlayers($scope.pickupleague);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks Devqon. I may be missing something but I when I added your suggested code I get the following error:

**TypeError: Pickupleagues.get(...).then is not a function**

Comment: It depends on what your `Pickupleagues.get()` function is. Is it a `$resource` function? does it return a promise?

Comment: I don't believe it is a resource function. I am using Mean.js for this project. It seemed like a good idea because it had everything I was looking to learn. This was a default function when I created the controller/modal/views with a yeoman command. TBH I thought it was a default request. Would it make sense to switch it from the current structure to an $http.get function?

Comment: @JustAskMedia post your Pickupleagues.get() function. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to devqon's help, I was able to get on the right track. I switched loading the data from the Pickupleagues.get() and instead used $http.get() instead. This let me get a success statement on completion of the data being loaded. I am then able to call out the functions needed.

```
$http.get('/pickupleagues/'+ $stateParams.pickupleagueId).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.pickupleague = data;
        $scope.listPlayers = $scope.setSubscribedPlayers();
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Hopefully this helps solution helps someone else. It turns out using the default Mean.js call may not be the best solution for a situation like this.